# "Autoplay" in audio tag not working google chrome

Tags: html, css

I have searched so much but I can't find an alternative!
Here is my code:

```
<audio autoplay>
     <source src="music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is only one `source` tag, you can put the source in the audio tag's `src` attribute.

```html
<audio autoplay src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3"></audio>
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/8850s/L5uzb34y/

Note that this may not work in the [StackSnippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) above.

Comment: That code works in JSfiddle but not on my website for some reason

Comment: @AsherDUBZ Try changing the `src` to `music.mp3`. It could be because of CORS.

Comment: @AsherDUBZ It stands for cross-origin resource sharing

Comment: I tried it, **still nothing :(**

Comment: i'll just use a button then

Answer (score 1):

As you may have noticed, web browsers are moving towards stricter autoplay policies in order to improve the user experience, minimize incentives to install ad blockers, and reduce data consumption on expensive and/or constrained networks. These changes are intended to give greater control of playback to users and to benefit publishers with legitimate use cases.

Chrome's autoplay policies are simple:

Muted autoplay is always allowed.
Autoplay with sound is allowed if:
User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning the user has previously played video with sound.
The user has added the site to their home screen on mobile or installed the PWA on desktop.
Top frames can delegate autoplay permission to their iframes to allow autoplay with sound.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

```
allow="autoplay"
```

is also a possibility. Other than that you might want to experiment with the  tag

```
<audio controls></audio>
```